# Redirect the output to two different files, One should have new output whenever the commands execute and the other should have both new & old content

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, command

Redirect the output to two different files, One should have new output whenever the commands execute and the other should have both new & old content.

For example:

```
 openstack port create --network testnetwork1 test1-subport110 --disable-port-security --no-security-group
```

I need to redirect output into 2 different file. File A.txt and B.txt. Whenever executed the openstack port create command the new output should be in A.txt and old & new output should be in B.txt.

I want like below,

```
cat A.txt
port2UUID

cat B.txt
port1.UUID
port2.UUID
```

Kindly help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cmd | tee A.txt >> B.txt
```

Or

```
cmd | tee -a B.txt > A.txt
```

Would `tee` (think of a plumber's T) `cmd`'s output both into `A.txt` and in *append* mode into `B.txt`.

With the `zsh` shell, you can also do:

```
cmd > A.txt >> B.txt
```

(where `zsh` does the `T`'ing internally by itself when redirecting the same file descriptor several times).

---

To include `cmd`'s stderr into the inflow of the T, use:

```
cmd 2>&1 | tee A.txt >> B.txt
```

Or in `zsh`:

```
cmd > A.txt >> B.txt 2>&1
```

Or:

```
cmd >& A.txt >>& B.txt
```

Comment: thanks. can i pass the stderr in this same command

        cmd | tee A.txt >> B.txt  2>&1

Comment: @Beginner, see edit.